# Docker IPv6 Protocol family unavailable

Tags: java, docker, ipv6

How to use IPv6 inside docker container ?
On try to bind IPv6 address I got exception: `java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable`

On host IPv6 work correctly.

I tried [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/) but it not help.
Also i use `--network host` option.

Comment: Is the call coming outside of docker or docker is trying to call other external service or other docker machine ?

Comment: @TraychoIvanov try call for example google.com [2a00:1450:401b:807::200e]. But it doesn't even come to that. Because i got exception on bind(SocketAddress bindpoint) method.

Answer (score 0):

One options is to use IPv4 within your JVM.

To prevent your JVM from doing this, set the following two system properties to true:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true
```

If you have Dockerfile which runs java application check adding

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true"
```

If you still target IPv6, please have a look over there https://collabnix.com/enabling-ipv6-functionality-for-docker-and-docker-compose/

Make sure to verify your ipv6 is up and running before starting the java app.

Comment: I definitely need IPv6.

Comment: @KopeMorta Have update with extra link with more details.

Comment: I already tried edit ```/etc/docker/daemon.json``` file. This added ipv6 address to docker0 interface, but i still have same exception.
I also use host network, why i have this exception ?
If I had problems with incorrect IPv6 configuration, there would be other errors. This is some kind of error that prohibits the use of these addresses. And of course, the network is configured correctly, because everything works without a docker.